# Method in attribute actionListener is not called after click button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a question about `jsf` framework. This is my controller:

### controller

```
package controller;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
#public class Controller implements Serializable {

    private boolean blView;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        blView = true;
    }

    public void add() {
        System.out.println("This is method add");
        blView = false;
    }

    public void back() {
        System.out.println("This is method back");
        blView = true;
    }

    public boolean isBlView() {
        return blView;
    }

    public void setBlView(boolean blView) {
        this.blView = blView;
    }

}
```

### File index.xhtml

> ```
>  <h:form id="frmView" >
>         <p:panel id="pnlControl">
>             <p:commandButton id="p1" actionListener="#{controller.back()}" immediate="true" rendered="#{!controller.blView}"
>                              process="@this" value="Back" update=":frmView:pnlControl :frmView:pnlAdd"/>
>
>           <p:commandButton id="p2" actionListener="#{controller.add()}" immediate="true" rendered="#{controller.blView}" 
>                              value="Add" process="@this" update=":frmView:pnlControl :frmView:pnlAdd"/>
>
>      </p:panel>
>
>      <p:panel id="pnlAdd" visible="#{!controller.blView}">
>             <p:panelGrid columns="2" >
>                 <f:facet name="header" >
>                     Info
>                 </f:facet>
>
>             <h:outputLabel value="Name: " />
>                 <h:inputText value="Hello Viet Nam." />
>
>        </p:panelGrid>
>
>    </p:panel>
> ```

So, when I added or deleted attribute `actionListener="#controller.back()}"`, the method `back()` are not enforced when I click on the button. Thank advance.

Comment: To reach the culprit closer, try removing the `immediate` attribute just as an additional exercise to see, if it makes a difference. (And a pair of parentheses after a method name in `actionListener` is unnecessary in this case).

Comment: i removed the immediate attribute and a pair of parentheses after a method name in actionListener. But the problem don't resolve. when i remove rendered="#{!controller.blView}" by render="true" then the method back() will enforce.

Comment: I copy/pasted the code in a test environment. I saw both the methods being invoked correctly. Did you import the view scoped annotation correctly, `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` in this case?

Comment: Yes... Thank you so much... I had import  wrong library javax.faces.view.ViewScoped instead of library javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped . Thank you!!!

Comment: The JSF managed bean turns out to be request scoped in that case with that combination of annotations in which case the CDI annotation `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` would simply be ignored as if it were not present at all leaving the managed bean with the only annotation `@ManagedBean` which defaults to `@javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped`.

Comment: Yes. I tried to find error in my example, but i can't believe i add wrong library. I read about annotation. However, i need to learn more about JSF framework. Thank you. Because i can continue with my project.